# XSL tansform result of DOMXpath->evaluate in php

Tags: php, xslt, xpath

I have:

```php
$XML = new DOMDocument();
$XML->load('demo.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($XML);
$elements = $xpath->evaluate($_GET["xpath"]);

$XSL = new DOMDocument();
$XSL->load('xml2json.xsl', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($XSL);

echo $xslt->transformToXML($elements);
```

I get the following error:

```
( ! ) Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [xsltprocessor.transformtoxml]: Invalid Document in C:\wamp\www\content.php on line 18
```

How do I convert a DOMNodeList to a DOMDocument to make this work?

Here is how I got it to work!

```
function getContent(&$NodeContent="",$nod)
{    $NodList=$nod->childNodes;
    for( $j=0 ;  $j < $NodList->length; $j++ )
    {       $nod2=$NodList->item($j);//Node j
        $nodemane=$nod2->nodeName;
        $nodevalue=$nod2->nodeValue;
        if($nod2->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE)
            $NodeContent .=  $nodevalue;
        else
        {     $NodeContent .= "<$nodemane";
           $attAre=$nod2->attributes;
           foreach ($attAre as $value)
              $NodeContent .=" {$value->nodeName}='{$value->nodeValue}'" ;
            $NodeContent .=">";                    
            getContent($NodeContent,$nod2);                    
            $NodeContent .= "</$nodemane>";
        }
    }

}


$XML = new DOMDocument();
$XML->load('demo.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($XML);
$elements = $xpath->query($_GET["xpath"]);

$XSL = new DOMDocument();
$XSL->load('xml2json.xsl', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($XSL);

$newdoc = new DOMDocument;
$newdoc -> preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$newdoc -> formatOutput = true; 

$elm = $elements->item(0);
getContent($docstring,$elm);
$docstring = '<root>'.$docstring.'</root>';
$docstring = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), '', $docstring);
$newdoc -> LoadXML($docstring);
echo $xslt->transformToXML($newdoc);
```

Comment: There should be a close flag for "RTFE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing

```
$elements = $xpath->evaluate($_GET["xpath"]);
…
echo $xslt->transformToXML($elements);
```

The [return values for `DOMXPath::evaluate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) are

> Returns a typed result if possible or a `DOMNodeList` containing all nodes matching the given XPath expression. If the expression is malformed or the contextnode is invalid, `DOMXPath::evaluate()` returns `FALSE`.

The [method signature for `transformToXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php) states

```
string XSLTProcessor::transformToXML ( DOMDocument $doc )
```

In other words, you are not passing a `DOMDocument` and get an "Invalid Document" error.

Comment: Hi, Yes but how do I convert it to a document in this example?

Comment: Create a new DOMDocument. Import and Append the result nodes.

Comment: Thanks I do get the problem I just don't have a solution. I have search creating a DOMDocument from DOMNodeList with no luck. Can you please provide a code sample?

Comment: @tnt tbh, I dont want to provide you a code sample. This is not rocket science. The keywords are [DOMDocument](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), [import](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) and [append](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php). So check the docs. I know you can solve this on your own.

Comment: you are funny! I think rocket science is relative!

Comment: @tnt well if it works, it works, but I was really thinking you'd just adapt the first example code given at importNode manual page.